# What are the image locations for deployment from mac os to linux/docker production host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've just built my docker image locally with `docker-compose build` on my Mac(Big Sur, Docker 20.04).

`docker images` tells me:

```
REPOSITORY           TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
mariadb_mymariadb   latest    fb2718607a38   4 weeks ago   388MB
```

As an aside: the CREATED information of "4 weeks ago" is wrong here. As I wrote, I've just built it. I am 100% sure about that, because the result of `docker images` was empty before I ran `docker-compose build`.

So, now I'd like to upload that to my production docker host.

Here are my questions:

- Where is the image ***mariadb_mymariadb*** located on Mac?
- What's the target directory for images on my linux/debian docker production host?

Comment: You need to publish your image with `docker image push ...` command. You can push on DockerHub or a private registry, then pull on your server with `docker image pull ...`. Alternatively you can export (`docker image save`) on your Mac then copy the resulting tarball on your server and load it with `docker image load`.

Comment: @zigam Awesome! That was basically what I was looking for: _`docker image save`_ and _`docker image load`_. If you turn this into an answer, I'll mark it as the appropirate answer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the benefits of using Docker is that you don't need to worry where the images are located or found. You just rely on the Docker host and its CLI to create and manage them.

On the Mac (if you really need to know) the image can be found at: see [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/where-are-images-stored-on-mac-os-x/17165)

On your local development environment build and run the images to ensure all works as expected.

```
docker build myimage:latest .
docker run myimage:latest -p 8080:8080 # etc...
```

Once you are happy you can push them into a Docker registry ([DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/) is free when your images are not private)

```
docker login
docker push myimage:latest
```

On your prod host you just pull the the images you need, then run them

```
docker login
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: I don't mind to worrying about image locations. I think that might be simpler than going through some third party registry.

Is using DockerHub the only way to get an image deployed to a production host?

Comment: Most public cloud providers have their own image registry offering; there at least used to be a couple of third-party ones; I believe GitHub has one these days; or you can run your own.  But using some sort of registry is definitely the preferred path.

Comment: Using a Docker registry you have several advantages over copying manually the image tar files: use Docker cli security (no need to SCP-SSH into the prod host), incremental copy (push only the changes), convenient if you have multiple servers (ie deploy same image to an Acceptance host)